# self referencing in the same table in fluent n hibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have to map a Company to its own parentCompany with a column other than the CompanyId which is the unique identifier I am unable to write the mapping configuration for the same.

```
      public class Company
     {
     public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual State StateRef { get; set; }
    public virtual long? DUNS { get; set; }
    public virtual long? DUNSUltimateParent { get; set; }
    public virtual Company UltimateParentCompany { get; set; }
    }
```

For a particular company , the DUNS number is unique but the primary key is CompanyId . and the corresponding UltimateParentCompany should be mapped through DUNSUltimateParent column to DUNS column.
Hope I am clear.

I have come up with this below mapping which is not working as it is searching for companyId and not in DUNS.

```
  References(x => x.UltimateParentCompany).Column("DUNSUltimateParent")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Company
     {
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Parent{ get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Company>Children{get;set}
    }

References(x => x.Parent, "ParentId").Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.Children).Cascade.SaveUpdate().KeyColumn("ParentId");
```

This is how self referencing should look like.

Comment: No That did not work ..  The unique id for self referencing is not the primary key of the table rather a different column called DUNS , DUNSUltimateParent.